# How do I show language consisting prime number of 0s or prime number of 1s is not context-free?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

The language is: `L1 = {w | n0(w) or n1(w) is prime}`

n0 means number of 0s and n1 means number of 1s I can show a^n (n is prime) is not context-free. But I can't find any solution for this one.

Comment: IIRC there is a version of the pumping lemma for context-free languages. Check one of those proofs if you find one, they are all very similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose it is context-free and let $n$ be the pumping length.

Consider $u = 0^p$, where $p$ is any prime number greater than $n$. It is clear that $u \in L$. The pumping lemma for context-free languages states that there exists a decomposition $u = vwxyz$ such that:

1. $|wxy| \leqslant n$;
2. $|wy| > 0$;
3. for any $k\geqslant 0$, $vw^kxy^kz\in L$.

But for $k = p + 1$, $|vw^kxy^kz| = p + p |wy| = p(|wy| + 1)$ is not a prime number. We conclude that $vw^kxy^kz\notin L$ and by contradiction that $L$ is not context-free.